# How to get unused window height in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to get the total unused window height, which my application can not consume from total device height, like- status bar or any other decorated views.

Answer (score 0):

First get the total height of the screen using display metrics. Then find the height of status bar and action bar (if you are using) and subtract these from screen height.

Comment: Some other decorated View may also be present on the device. How to get all of them's height.